# Place references to IBOutlet and IBAction inside viewDidLoad or just before?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewdidload

I understand that `viewDidLoad` is where you are supposed to put any set up code in relation to buttons, color, and other view related code. However, in a code sample I have just seen, a reference to IBOutlet and to IBAction are not written inside of viewDidLoad but rather, just before this method, as below. Are these not set up related code, as in creating a label and a method to manipulate it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func showName(sender: AnyObject) {
    nameLabel.text = "my name is Cyril"
}


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewDidLoad is only one method of setup. You can put some code here, local variables, ets. @IBOutlet and @IBAction are links of Interface Builder and nameLabel. And this outlet and action suppose to be global, so you could use them in other functions, not only in viewDidLoad.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameLabel.text = "my name is Cyril"
    }

}
```